# How can I edit the attributes of a product in the cart?

Tags: cart, product-attribute

I defined a couple of attributes for a product.
e.g. Project
Before Checkout I want the user to let change the Projectname
and store it in the database (quote_item),
which will be done by an observer-routine.

Or is there another method to add additional information to the cart line?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Product attributes is not really what you want.

You want Product Options.

Magento core will then deal with saving them during the order process.
You can then (later) access any quote item's selected product options using code as follows:

(untested)

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(**ORDER_ID**);
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item):
    $options = $item->getProductOptions();
    foreach ($options as $option):
            //$option contains the option information for item
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. To order multiple items at a time you have to add option(s) with quote item object. Here is the code snap for your help.

```
<?php 
$quoteObj=Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->assignCustomer($customerObj);
$productModel=Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

foreach($products as $product) {
$productObj = $productModel->load($productId);
$quoteItem = Mage::getModel('sales/quote_item')->setProduct($productObj);

$quoteItem->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                array(
                        'product' => $quoteItem->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'option_ids',
                        'value' => $option_id  // 45,46,55
                     )
            ));

$quoteItem->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                    array(
                        'product' => $quoteItem->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'option_'.$option_id,   //45
                        'value' => $option_value          // ‘White’
                     )
    ));

    $quoteItem->addOption(new Varien_Object(
                    array(
                        'product' => $quoteItem->getProduct(),
                        'code' => 'option_'.$option_id,   //46
                        'value' => $option_value         // ‘Large’
                    )
    ));

$quoteItem->setQuote($quoteObj);
$quoteItem->setQty($Quantity);
$quoteObj->addItem($quoteItem);
}
$quoteObj->collectTotals();
$quoteObj->save();
?>
```